# Em quantos milissegundos o evento drag é disparado?

Tags: javascript

No site do [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondrag.asp) eles menciona que o evento ocorre em 350 milissegundos:

> Note: While dragging an element, the ondrag event fires every 350 milliseconds.

Só que isso varia isso porque se eu arrastar um elemento e não move-lo ele vai ser disparado mais rápido ou seja vai ocorrer em uma quantidade menor de milissegundos agora se eu ficar arrastando e movendo o elemento ele vai ocorrer mais rápido ainda e em uma quantidade menor ainda de milissegundos.

**Exemplo:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #div1 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" draggable="true"></div>
    <p id="p1"></p>
    <script>
        let div1 = document.querySelector("#div1");
        let count = 0;

        div1.addEventListener("drag", function() {
            let p1 = document.querySelector("#p1");

            count ++;
            p1.innerHTML = `A div está sendo arrastada: ${count}`;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notem no exemplo acima se eu arrastar o elemento e ficar com o mouse parado a variável `count` é incrementada mais lenta e se eu ficar arrastando e movendo o mouse a variável `count` é incrementada mais rápida. Só para complementar isso também ocorre com o evento `mousemove`. Em quantos milissegundos é chamado o evento `drag` ou depende que nem mostrado no exemplo acima?

Comment: acho que não vai achar uma resposta exata para essa pergunta, tipo, *"são exatamente 291ms"*.. depende do sistema (computador), motor de renderização, talvez dos demais objetos no *document*... só de curiosidade, pq precisa desse valor?

Comment: Só quero saber por conhecimento mesmo, sou uma pessoa cética, não gosto de ter uma dúvida e não saber a resposta, também porque se outra pessoa me perguntar a mesma coisa eu não vou saber o que responder.

Comment: entendi... acho que não deve ter uma resposta certa e exata, Ao arrastar tem um processamento, do navegador, do computador, do motor de renderização do navegador desenhar novamente o objeto que foi arrastado pra outro ponto... isso não deve ser preciso, a resposta talvez seja "em torno de XXXms"

Comment: Valeu! por ter respondido pelo menos eu tive uma ideia do porque isso ocorrer com esse evento. Mas então o porque do W3schools ter estabelecido um valor fixo de milissegundos?

Comment: W3schools não é lá uma fonte muito boa - [já foi pior](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/7nxdd9/why_does_so_many_people_dislike_w3schools/), hj melhorou um pouco, mas eu prefiro consultar o [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event), que diz que o evento é disparado "every few hundred milliseconds", ou seja, não tem um valor exato, pois depende de vários fatores, como já mencionado acima

Comment: Obrigado! a todos vocês por terem respondido.

Answer (score 11):

Olá,

Os eventos de 'ondrag' (assim como outros do mesmo tipo, 'dragstart', 'dragenter', etc) implementam a interface 'DragEvent', da especificação do HTML5.

Esta interface define vários eventos e como estes devem ser acionados. Dentre outras coisas

Em relação a sua pergunta, você encontra no subtópico 5.7.5 uma descrição de como o user-agent deve se comportar quando o evento é disparado.

Dentre todo o conjunto de regras que precisam ser seguidas da especificação, você irá encontra o seguinte trecho:

> Citação: Os 'user-agent' devem, assim que a operação de arrastar for iniciada e a cada 350ms (± 200ms) daí em diante, enquanto a operação de arrastar estiver em andamento, enfileirar uma tarefa para executar as seguintes etapas em sequência:

Ou seja, a cada 350ms, com tolerancia de 200ms para mais ou para menos, o evento é disparado.

Em relação a ser mais rápido quando está arrastando, ocorre pois ao se arrastar, inicia-se um novo processamento dos eventos. Do contrário, fica nos 350ms até que se finalize o evento ao soltar o botão do mouse.

Abaixo o link para a seção citada.

[5.7.5 - Drag-and-drop processing models](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/editing.html#drag-and-drop-processing-model)